# HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject Always null from Class Library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a resx file in App_GlobalResources in my web application, called with:

```
Resources.GetResource("ResourceFileName", "Resource")
```

The helper method lives in a separate class library to get resource values:

```
using System.Resources;
using System.Web;

public static class Resources
{
    public static string GetResource(string resource, string key)
    {
        try
        {
            string resourceValue = (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject(resource, key);

            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(resourceValue) ? string.Empty : resourceValue;
        }
        catch (MissingManifestResourceException)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

If I hit F5, everything works fine. If I deploy to a web server, **all** calls to GetGlobalResourceObject come back as null.

The resources exist. How do I get them out?

Thanks,

Richard

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have same problem too and yes **"GetGlobalResourceObject(...)"** return always null after publish.

So, I found the solution by using instead of **'GetGlobalResourceObject("Captions","button_go_text")'** to **'Resources.Captions.ResourceManager.GetString(key)'**

Sample code is like below

```
    public static string GetResMsg(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string key)
    {
      try
      {
        return Resources.[resource class name].ResourceManager.GetString(key);
      }
      catch
      {
        return "?";
      }
    }
```

I hope that helps,

best regards

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this problem by setting the **Custom Tool** of my resource file to be **GlobalResourceProxyGenerator**

And the **Build Action** to **Content** and **Copy to Output Directory** property to **Copy Always**

[image: Resource File Properties]

If I didn't do this when I published to production calls to **HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject** would always return null.